# Final Value Problem Code: Reversing Vectors Inside of a Function

Tags: r, reverse, differential-equations

I'm currently writing a chunk of code to solve a system of differential equations, two are initial value problems and the final one is a final value problem. Naturally for the latter I've just reversed the equation and solved it as an IVP. (I'm using deSolve by the way). However, I find that there are multiple ways of reversing the vectors for my problem and only one way seems to give a sensible answer, the others all blow up crazily and I have no idea why.

Here is a snippet from the code that works (full code below for context):

```
linearzreverse<-function(times,y,parms){
    tt=tail(x,n=1)+1
    dw.dx<-(-(sol[tt-times,2]/(a*dt)+(p[1]-p[2]+a)/a))*y[1]-(sol2[tt-times,2]-resultsmatrix[tt-times,val])/(a*dt)
    return(list(dw.dx))
  }
  y2<-(-tail(sol2[,2],n=1)/tail(sol[,2],n=1))
  sol3<-ode(y=y2,times=x,func=linearzreverse,parms=p)
```

Here I've reversed the vectors sol, sol2 and a column of resultsmatrix by essentially making tt to be one more than the final value in my index set x and then reading the vectors backwards by using sol[tt-times,2] for example.

However, if I do the following instead using the rev() function

```
linearzreverse<-function(times,y,parms){
    dw.dx<-(-(rev(sol[,2])[times]/(a*dt)+(p[1]-p[2]+a)/a))*y[1]-(rev(sol2[,2])[times]-rev(resultsmatrix[,val])[times])/(a*dt)
    return(list(dw.dx))
  }
  y2<-(-tail(sol2[,2],n=1)/tail(sol[,2],n=1))
  sol3<-ode(y=y2,times=x,func=linearzreverse,parms=p)
```

I get a solution that blows up. Even just defining the reversed vectors before putting them into the function blows up too.

Does anyone know why the results change when surely all I'm doing is reversing the vectors in different ways?

Thanks a lot and for full context I'll include the full code here:

```
library(deSolve)
tstar=1
n<-100 #determines time intervals
dt<-tstar/n
t=seq(from=0,to=tstar,by=dt)
L=100
M=100
x=seq(from=1,to=L+M,by=1)
v0<-ifelse(1-exp(x-L)<0,0,1-exp(x-L)) #initial condition
#chosen constants for the problem
a=0.25
r=0.12
D=0.1
#blank matricies to store each successive output 
resultsmatrix=matrix(data=0,nrow=length(x),ncol=length(t))
solmatrix=matrix(data=0,nrow=length(x),ncol=length(t)-1)
sol2matrix=matrix(data=0,nrow=length(x),ncol=length(t)-1)
sol3matrix=matrix(data=0,nrow=length(x),ncol=length(t)-1)
#first column is initial condition
resultsmatrix[,1]=v0

riccati<-function(times,y,parms){
  dU.dx<-1-y[1]*((p[1]-p[2]+a)/a)-(y[1]^2)/(a*dt)
  return(list(dU.dx))
}

#loop for solving the system of ODEs at each time step
for(val in (1:length(t[-1]))){
  p<-c(r,D)
  y0<-0
  sol<-ode(y=y0,times=x,func=riccati,parms=p)
  solmatrix[,val]=sol[,2]
  linear<-function(times,y,parms){
    du.dx<-(sol[times,2]/(a*dt))*(resultsmatrix[times,val]-y[1])#if this break, try adding [] to make sol[[times,2]] and make change at * too
    return(list(du.dx))
  }
  y1<-1
  sol2<-ode(y=y1,times=x,func=linear,parms=NULL)
  sol2matrix[,val]=sol2[,2]
  linearzreverse<-function(times,y,parms){
    tt=tail(x,n=1)+1
    dw.dx<-(-(sol[tt-times,2]/(a*dt)+(p[1]-p[2]+a)/a))*y[1]-(sol2[tt-times,2]-resultsmatrix[tt-times,val])/(a*dt) #*
    return(list(dw.dx))
  }
  y2<-(-tail(sol2[,2],n=1)/tail(sol[,2],n=1))
  sol3<-ode(y=y2,times=x,func=linearzreverse,parms=p)
  sol3matrix[,val]=rev(sol3[,2])
  resultsmatrix[,val+1]=sol[,2]*rev(sol3[,2])+sol2[,2]
}
#Transforming the problem into the form needed for my work
S=50
yvals=x-L
K=S*exp(yvals)
DiscountResults=S*resultsmatrix%*%diag(exp(-D*t))
truncno=101 #101 for L=M=100
persp(x=head(K,n=truncno),y=t,z=head(DiscountResults,n=truncno),
      xlab="K",ylab="t",zlab="V(K,t)",main="Stock Price S=50", theta = 50, phi = 25,
      ticktype="detailed",axes=T)
#plot(head(K,n=truncno),head(S*resultsmatrix[,101],n=truncno),type="l")
#Plots to track the three individual differential equations
persp(x=x,y=t[-1],z=solmatrix,
      xlab="x",ylab="t",zlab="U_n(x,tau)",main="Stock Price S=50", theta = 50, phi = 25,
      ticktype="detailed",axes=T)
persp(x=x,y=t[-1],z=sol2matrix,
      xlab="x",ylab="t",zlab="u_n(x,tau)",main="Stock Price S=50", theta = 50, phi = 25,
      ticktype="detailed",axes=T)
persp(x=x,y=t[-1],z=sol3matrix,
      xlab="x",ylab="t",zlab="z_n(x,tau)",main="Stock Price S=50", theta = 50, phi = 25,
      ticktype="detailed",axes=T)
```

Comment: Does it not work to simply give a reversed time array to the ODE solver? The more professional packages all can handle negative step sizes.

Comment: The current version of deSolve cannot work with negative time steps, this was sacrificed for some other features that make it more user friendly. You can apply the following trick: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-dynamic-models/2011q3/000086.html or try another solver package, see https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/DifferentialEquations.html

Comment: @tpetzoldt I don't think that trick will work for me because having the times be negative numbers leads to errors when trying to find sol[times,2] since I cant specify a negative row number (unless there is a way around this?). Which other package would be a good choice? I'm very unfamiliar with them all!

Comment: It is always possible to do an index computation, e.g. `sol[something - times, 2]`